# Name of this attack?

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography

I am studying [Merkle tree signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_signature_scheme). Let $\sigma=(s,Y_s,\sigma_{\text{OTS}},As)$ be a signature of certain document. Here $s$ is the index of leaf, $Y_s$ is the respectively OTS public key and $A_s$ is the authentication path. My questions are:

1) Is there any attack where an adversary changes part of the signature $\sigma$? (For example suppose the adversary changes $\sigma_{\text{OTS}}$ to $\sigma^{*}_{\text{OTS}}$ for her or his convenience).

2) If that attack exist what is the name of that attack?

Comment: If there were such an attack, it would be called a *forgery*.  The part of the reasoning behind Merkle is that there is no computationally feasible way for doing that.  BTW: there's no particular need for a Merkle signature to explicitly include the OTS public key; the verifier can compute the required public key (from the hash and $\sigma_{OTS}$, and then validate that computed public key using the authentication path.

Comment: @poncho according the postquantum cryptography book of Sendried and et al. it is necessary $Y_s$ in the Merkle signature. Could you explain me please how retrieve $Y_s$ using $\sigma_{\text{OTS}}$ and the hash?

Comment: You take the OTS signature and the hash of the message; you compute the forward hash of the OTS signature (according to the bits of the message hash); that gives you an (unauthenticated) value of $Y_s$.  You then validate that value of $Y_s$ by computing up the authentication path; if you get the top level hash value, the signature verifies.

Comment: @poncho Before, $Y_s$  be validated, first needs validation with $X_s$. Then I think that it is necessary ...

Comment: $X_s$?  What is $X_s$ is the notation you're using?

Comment: @poncho What you are describing only works for some OTS, namely Winternitz and the optimized version of Lamport's scheme that Merkle describes in his original paper. For Lamport's scheme this does not work, at least you would have to send all the public key values for which you do not send secret key values with the signature (which is only half the public key).
Besides, $X_s$ is the one-time secret key for index $s$.